# Infinite redirection login loop in CAS-SSO & Spring Security with Spring Boot 3.1

Tags: spring, authentication, security, oauth, cas

Versions:

Spring Boot : 3.1.1
Spring Security : 6.1.1
Spring OAuth: 6.1.1

The endpoint for CAS tried with the following
1./j_spring_cas_security_check
2./login/cas

The following annotations
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)

replaced with
@EnableMethodSecurity and appropriate changes are made as per spring migration upgrade,

with the above changes getting Infinite redirection login loop from CAS